Solana Durable Nounce in Python
Could someone share an example how to use durable nounce in Python. Currently, my use case is that I want to create a limit order to be execute later on, but I want to use connect wallet to allow the user to sign the transaction ahead of time (not expiring)

Hey did you manage to figure this out?
